# Why is this text off screen?

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't figure out why this text in the bottom right corner is over scanning. I don't know what else to say about this problem, I think its pretty self explanatory, but SO keeps telling my my code to question ratio is to large so I have to add this little but of nonsense test here at the beginning.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="DeleteMe.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeleteMe"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Border Padding="10" Grid.Row="0"></Border>
      <StatusBar Grid.Row="1">
         <StatusBarItem>
            <Grid Width="794">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ProgressBar x:Name="UI_ProgressBar"
                               Height="16"
                               Width="180"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Value="{Binding ProgressValue}" />
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="2">
                  <Run Text="Visible Time: " /><Run Text="{Binding DisplayTime, FallbackValue=00:00:00.000}" />
               </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
         </StatusBarItem>
      </StatusBar>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public string DisplayTime { get; set; }
   public int ProgressValue { get; set; }
   public MainWindow ()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
      DisplayTime = "01:23:45.678";
      ProgressValue = 50;
   }
}
```

**Problem**
[image]
[image]

Comment: `<Grid Width="794">` is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Clemens but the window width is set to 800 ( >794 ) and the preview xaml preview shows it correctly.

Comment: Sure, but at runtime the window border is bigger.

Comment: You have 3 columns, but only using two of them... Put the `TextBlock` in the 1 column and set the `HorizontalAlignment` to right and column width to `*`, may just work, haven't tried it.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ the middle column is just there to take up the unused space. I was planning on having a few more things in the status bar but ran into this issue before the others where added.

Comment: @master_ruko and is causing you problems...

Comment: You should have three StatusBarItems instead.

Comment: @thanks, Ill try that. I'm still learning WPF so little things like this trip me up still.

Comment: @Clemens OK, I'll change that too. was going of an example I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a fixed-size Grid in a single StatusBarItem, there should be three StatusBarItems:

```
<StatusBar Grid.Row="1">
    <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <ProgressBar x:Name="UI_ProgressBar"
                     Height="16" Width="180" Value="{Binding ProgressValue}" />
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Visible Time:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding DisplayTime, FallbackValue=00:00:00.000}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem /> <!-- last child fills remaining space -->
</StatusBar>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know you could treat a ```StatusBar``` like a ```DockPanel```.

Comment: It uses a DockPanel as its ItemsPanel. You could replace that with any other Panel if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `*` sizing to be the time column and do the middle column to `auto` instead.

The reason is that when the sizing calculations are occurring the full size is not available and hence not being calculated. If you are not using the middle section, then changing the last column to take up all the space by `*` would be better. You might have to align the text to the right at that point.